# CDN For MDBootsrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

how to add MDBootstrap in web project

i couldnt found the cdn for bootstraps

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**css**

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wsl-widget-css'  href='https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/assets/css/style.css?ver=5.6.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='compiled.css-css'  href='https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/css/compiled-4.19.2.min.css?ver=4.19.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Script CDN

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/js/bundles/4.19.2/compiled.192.min.js?ver=4.19.2' id='mdb-js2-js'></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' id='compiled.css-css'  href='https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/css/compiled-4.19.2.min.css?ver=4.19.2' type='text/css' media='all' />

    //sweetalert
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" id="theme-styles">
```